# Error 1010 in ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop

After compiling and running my program, i run into runtime error 1010:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at DC/updateScore()[DC::frame74:36]
```

This is the piece of code:

```
function updateScore(e:MouseEvent) {
var i:uint=0;
for(;i<balls.length;i++)
    if(balls[i]==e.target)
        break;
if(balls[i].isCorrect) {
    score++;
    timeField.text = new String(score);
}
else {
    score--;
    timeField.text = new String(score);
}
}
```

What's the problem? I'm using updateScore function for MouseEvent listener, as you can see.

Answer (score 3):

Please put { and } to your for loop!

```
function updateScore(e:MouseEvent) {
    var i:uint=0;
    for(;i<balls.length;i++) {
            if(balls[i]==e.target)
                break;
        if(balls[i].isCorrect) {
            score++;
            timeField.text = new String(score);
        }
        else {
            score--;
            timeField.text = new String(score);
        }
    }
}
```

Its allowed not to use { and } with a loop but then only the first statement will be excuted.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you are trying to manipulate properties of a undefined variable. You are probably trying to access `balls[i]` when there is no element on the i-th position. Or possibly there is another object without the property you want to access.

At what line do you get the error. Are you sure `balls[i].isCorrect` is a valid property.

Answer (score 1):

@Jens answer has it, but his explanation is confusing.

When your loop exits,

```
i = balls.length
```

On the next line, you're referencing

```
balls[i].isCorrect.
```

On that particular line, i is 1 greater than the greatest index in balls. Hence, exception.

While you may not want each of those lines to execute for each repetition of the loop as Jens thought, you've got to address this.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the first rule in your for loop:

```
for(;i<balls.length;i++)
```

I think you meant

```
for(i;i<balls.length;i++)
```

Comment: it's not the point. it's legal. anyway, problem existed before i deleted the first rule in the loop.

Comment: Have you checked that after you break the loop balls[i] actually contains something?

Comment: why? is that possible to balls[i] not to contain anything? i'm perfectly sure it does.

Comment: if `balls[i]==e.target` never equals true, then `i` will be incremented beyond the available indexes of your array

Comment: that's also impossible. i'm perfectly sure about that.

Comment: Original answer was useless, tempting me to -1, but comments are useful. Nika, you may be *absolutely sure*, but it's the *only* source of potential error in your code.

Comment: @sam - I won't edit because the comments would cease to make sense. Best it drops to the bottom and you and Jens get voted up. Feel free to -1.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
if(!balls){
   trace('balls missing');
   return;
}
```

before loop declaration

Comment: then try tracing `balls[i]` before checking `balls[i].isCorrect`

Answer (score 0):

based on the little code you've provided, you've either not instantiated the `balls` vector or the `timeFiled` textField.

```
var balls:Vector<Ball>;
balls.push(new Ball(whatever), new Ball(whatever), new Ball(whatever));
trace(balls);

//ERROR
//you must initialize the vector:  var vector:Vector<Ball> = new <Ball>;
```

which part of the code is on line 36?

the problem may also be with the `Ball` object's `isCorrect` property.